# Does Apple allow crypto-currency mining in ios app?

Tags: ios-appstore

I have been looking into the feasibility of creating an app that mines crypto-currency. I have been searching the appstore for similar apps but none have come up where the miner is part of the app.

Does anyone know if Apple allows mining on device from an approved app?

Answer (score 3):

[Section 3.1.5 Cryptocurrencies](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#cryptocurrencies) explains in specific detail what review guidelines affect mining apps on device as well as address monetary wallet apps.

> Apps may not mine for cryptocurrencies unless the processing is performed off device.

In 2017 the guidelines were not as clear [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

Back then, section [2.4.2](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#hardware-compatibility) contained the following:

> Design your app to use power efficiently. Apps should not rapidly drain battery, generate excessive heat, or put unnecessary strain on device resources.

Use of that clause to reject any crypto currency mining, which would by definition be CPU/GPU intentive, was always possible and now that potential ban is explicit.

Answer (score -5):

Apple prohibits direct mining of cryptocurrencies on iPhone and iPad. The Cupertino-based company has updated its app developer guidelines. ... In the future, apps that mine directly on the devices will be banned.

I've familiarized myself with an app and can only talk about it well. The app makes it possible to verify the transactions between cryptocurrencies in order to get a share of the falling fees. The app mints the XMRig (Monero) algorithm as it only uses the CPU because most of them are more likely to have a better CPU than CPU. You want it to be usable for everyone.But that doesn't work on iOS, but on macOS. A demo is running on iOS that shows the hash rate but still gives BItcoins for it.

I do not notice any loss of performance or any loss of battery. In the battery category in the settings, I can see that the app uses approx. 1-2% of the battery. Depending on how often you have them in the forground.

According to the app's quote, only a demo is running on the devices. Nevertheless, the number of Bitcoins is increasing and 100% can be paid out. (Everything checked by myself) [CryptoTab](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cryptotab-browser-mobile/id1446766940)

> Mining is not allowed on IOS devices, but you can use your smartphone
> or tablet to access server dependent mining. When you run the service
> on your device, the algorithm will calculate the speed you would get
> with real mining on the device and you will see a real hash rate.
> **Cryptocurrency that has been mined this way can be withdrawn to your
> CryptoTab account**

[image]

Comment: Your post starts with "Mining on iOS devices is not really prohibited" and then quotes an app description stating "Mining ist auf IOS-Geräten nicht erlaubt". Don't see how both can be true.

Comment: As written now, this answer starts out fundamentally wrong. Mining on device is explicitly prohibited as part of app review. I’ve updated the old answer to quote from Apple guidelines.

Comment: Aua -3 down votes. Is the post really that bad? To the community. Is the post really that bad? Wrong information somewhere?

Comment: It's always hard to say. But in the specific case (as already commented) the initial version was just plain wrong and inconsistent. The edit of the first paragraph helped but lacks a reference, the rest seems to be irrelevant to the question (and the answer).

Comment: Don’t sweat any votes for a 3 week period is my advice. They are little nudges. It seems you are answering a different question than the one being asked to me which makes this not so useful. I am glad this was bumped by the “community robot” eight hours ago since an edit was clearly needed from the  2017 answer.